# Symfony 2 add dynamic form; values from database

Tags: php, symfony, dynamicform

I would like to create a google categories matching(first field categorie from database and second field a user autocomplete field from google categories) form where i have an entity CategoriesConfig :

```
 private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="category_site", type="string", length=100)
 */
private $categorySite;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="category_google", type="string", length=100)
 */
private $categoryGoogle;
```

In my Controller i tried this

```
 /**
 * @Route("/adminDashboard/categoriesMatching", name="googleShopping_categories")
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')")
 */
public function categoriesMatchingAction(Request $request)
{
    // create a task and give it some dummy data for this example
    $idSite = $this->get('session')->get('_defaultWebSite')->getId();
    $categories = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('DataSiteBundle:SiteCategory')->findBy(array('IdSite' => $idSite));;
    $categories_config = new CategoriesConfig();
    //var_dump($categories);exit;
    $form = $this->createForm(new CategoriesConfigType($categories), $categories_config);


    return $this->render('GoogleShoppingBundle:Default:categoriesMatching.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

And my form type : CategoriesConfigType:

```
    class CategoriesConfigType extends AbstractType
    {
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    private $site_categories;

     public function __construct ($site_categories) {
        $this->site_categories = $site_categories;
    }
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {   
        foreach($this->site_categories as $k => $categorie){
            $builder
                ->add('categorySite')
                ->add('categoryGoogle');
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Sp\GoogleShoppingBundle\Entity\CategoriesConfig'
        ));
    }
  }
```

I would like to have as many categories rows as row fields(website itecategorie and google categorie)

The result is like that:

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is your problem ?

Comment: I didn't get a dynamic form, i got a form containig one field for categorie and another for google category, i would like to as as many categories as fields, it's clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop on `$this->categories` is uneffective, because the elements you add have the same name each time (`categorySite` and `categoryGoogle`), so the FormBuilder replaces the form field each time, instead of adding another one.

However, if you want your form to handle a Collection of CategoryConfigs, you need to take a different approach.

1) Create a `CategoriesConfigType` (as you did), but who is responsible of only **a single CategoriesConfig entity**

```
class CategoriesConfigType extends AbstractType
{     
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {   
        $builder
            ->add('categorySite')
            ->add('categoryGoogle');
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Sp\GoogleShoppingBundle\Entity\CategoriesConfig'
        ));
    }
}
```

2) Then use [CollectionType field](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) to manipulate your form as a whole collection of CategoryConfigTypes:

```
class YourCollectionType extends AbstractType
{     
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {   
        $builder->add('categoriesConfigs', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type'   => CategoriesConfigType::class,
            'entry_options'  => array('required'  => false)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you i will test it and get you informed

Comment: YourCollectionType is another form type?

Comment: Yes. Name it as you want, it's the FormType you will have to render in your Controller.

Comment: i created an entity that contains cateogoriesSite array and googleCategories as array which is related with the new form type that you mentioned, is it right?

Comment: Not necessarily, depends on what you want to do with your categoriesConfig when the form is submitted. If you only need to iterate on them, do not specify any `data_class` in `YourCollectionType`, and pass an array `array('categoriesConfigs' => array())` to the FormBuilder.

Comment: i would like pass the website categories to be displayed in the form

Comment: then replace `array('categoriesConfigs' => array())` by `array('categoriesConfigs' => $yourCategoriesArray)`

Comment: where i didn't see any array('categoriesConfigs' => array())

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101703/discussion-between-sogara-and-tarek-fellah).